# How to count unique values from vector?

Tags: r, unique

I have:

```
c(17,20,30,12,30,20,17,20)
```

I want:

```
data.frame(c(1,2,3,2),c(12,17,20,30))
```

So unique values for the first vector shall be counted and sorted. the number of the counting should be in the first array.

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(x))`

Comment: Since the counts are needed in the first column, a tweak to @Sotos' solution: `rev(as.data.frame(table(x)))`